# JS iOS FileReader reading file twice causing JSON.parse to fail

Tags: javascript, ios, json, cordova, filereader

my app is initializing and checks for a file, if it exists it reads in the contents as a json and parses it.  In Android this is all working fine, but in iOS the same file reading/parsing function is somehow reading the file contents twice and is storing them as in invalid json object thus parsing it fails.

// call file to read;

```
            // filename    //dir  //success  //fail      //next step
readFromFile('userdata.json', 0, yesFile(0), errRFF(1052), checkRegister);
```

// read the file;

```
function readFromFile(fileName, dir, success, error, doRegister) {
  if (dir == 0) {
    var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory ;
    // Android:  file:///data/data/com.appName/files/
    // iOS: NoCloud/
  } else if (dir == 1) {
    var filePath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory ;
    // Android: /project/platforms/android/assets/
    // iOS: appname.app/
  }

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath + fileName, function (fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log("A") ;
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          console.log("B :" +this.result)

          // in iOS only, somehow `this.result` getting file contents TWICE
          // B : { ..json values #1...correct..
          //    }{ ..json values #1 again...not correct..
          //    }
          // this is causing a malformed json object
          //
          // in Android console prints out just:
          // B : { ..json values #1...correct..
          //    }
          // as a result, in iOS only, passing parsed JSON to success is failing

          success(JSON.parse(this.result),doRegister);
          console.log("C") ;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
      }, function(e) {error(fileName,e,doRegister)}) ;
  },function(e) {error(fileName,e,doRegister)});
}
```

Comment: from where are you calling readFromFile ? AppDelegate or somewhere else ?

Comment: Maybe a bit dirty hack but try `new Response(file).json().then(success, error)`